# eevee material has no depth

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine

I have a simple brick texture applied to a plane. When I view it in rendered mode in cycles, it has depth. But when I render it in eevee, it's just like an image being applied to a plane. Why? I'm trying to effect the seen with a bloom effect
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZW6S.jpg)

Comment: Hello :). Some nodes (like *Displacement*) are not yet fully supported in Eevee. Please, add a screenshot of your node setup. Without that, it's just guessing.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I'm trying to effect the material with a bloom effect. Is that even possible?

Comment: @Pro Effects Max no it's not.